# Populating new data frame column from parameterised SQL call

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame whose single column `tbl_name` contains a list of tables from my SQLite database:

```python
tables = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'", db)
```

I would like to add a column containing the count of rows from each table in the database. I would expect this to work:

```python
tables['count'] = tables.apply(lambda row : pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {row['tbl_name'}", db).iloc[0,0])
```

This throws a key error. What should this line look like?

Even stranger, to diagnose the problem I tried just using the row count from one table:

```python
pd.read_sql_query(f'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM help_infotip', db).iloc[0,0]
```

```
>> 3
```

but

```python
tables['count'] = tables.apply(lambda row : pd.read_sql_query(f'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM help_infotip', db).iloc[0,0])
```

results in a column of only NaN values, not 3s!

I'm clearly getting something fundamental wrong, but I cannot see what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tables['count'] = tables.tbl_name.apply(lambda row : pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {row}", db).iloc[0,0])
```

In your version, there is `axis=1` is missing, it should be like below:

```
tables['count'] = tables.apply(lambda row : pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {row['tbl_name']}", db).iloc[0,0], axis=1)
```